# Using swing to design eclipse menu

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin

As part of my homework assignment I have to create a documentation generator.

I decided to implement it as an eclipse plugin however I have run into a bit of a problem.

Basically what I wanted was that there would be a new menu called DocPreferences and when the user would click on it it should display a window asking for preferences of the HTML page that would be generated like background color, image etc.

So I created the window in Swing to collect information from the user and whenever the event handler for my menu is invoked I would create an object of the Swing class and invoke it to display the menu.

I then ran the project as an eclipse application and sure enough when I clicked on the window my UI designed in swing was displayed. However when I clicked the [close] button on the UI menu it also closed the eclipse application it was running on. Any help on how to get around this.

As an extra I'd also like to mention that all my UI has been designed in swing using a UI builder and since I do not know anything about SWT I'd prefer if there was a way to get around my problem without me having to redo all the work in SWT.

```
    //This code is part of a class called ColorChooser
    private void initComponents() {

    colorChooser = new javax.swing.JColorChooser();
    submit = new javax.swing.JButton();
    cancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
    label = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Then I set the layout of the components

    //This is the method which is invoked to start the application
    public void runner() {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ColorChooser().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}                  

//Finally in my handler class for the eclipse plugin the body of the execute method
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    new ColorChooser().runner();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is the Close button something that Eclipse generates or is that created by you UI builder?

Comment: the close button is the one on top of the window for which we write the setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE).

Comment: Can you post any code? In particular, around the `setDefaultCloseOperation()` method you mentioned?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code that you requested. I hope it helps in locating the source of the problem.